# Anima ad infinitum or anima infinita?

Tags: translation-check, english-to-latin-translation

Which phrase is correct, *anima ad infinitum* or *anima infinita*?

I want to say boundless soul, infinity soul.

Answer (score 4):

Both are possible, but the second option is probably more suitable.
The phrase *anima ad infinitum* means roughly "soul towards the infinity" whereas *anima infinita* is "unbounded soul".
If you want a description of the soul (it is an unbounded or infinite one), then pick *anima infinita*.
If you want to emphasize a process towards infinity (whatever that might mean), then *anima ad infinitum* sounds more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

"Boundless soul" (i.e. a soul without boundary or boundaries) could also be said

> anima sine fine/finibus

or

> anima sine termino/terminis

with options being singular/plural (boundary/boundaries).